# issue related to Locale class and when should it be used?

Tags: android

```
public static NoteItem getNew() {

    Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

My task here is to get the current date & time stamp from my device, but I have no idea why we have instantiate the Locale and with the constructor method "en_US".

I just simply can't understand this bit of code. can anyone gives me some explanation what is the sake of this bit of syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use the `Locale` instance when you want to display a date for example.

In the US the date format is not the same than in France or whatever. Using `Locale` will automatically do the job for you and will help your app to be the most consistant as possible.

For example, if you want to display the same date in two languages, you'll get something like

```
DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String formattedDate = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println("Date: " + formattedDate);
```

- In France, you'll get: `Date: 17.09.14 11:44`
- In the US, you'll have something slighty different: `Date: 9/17/14 11:44 AM`

Comment: hi, so are you trying to say that this bit of code is attempting to set the default locale as en_US? and return the date format in en_US? thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. This piece of code is setting the default `Locale` to the US time format for your whole application.